# Is this this mysql/php correct to delete a row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['dr'];
$dbhost = 'star***.***.edu';
$dbuser = '***4123';
$dbpass = '*****';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = "DELETE FROM address
        WHERE idnum=\"".$id\"";

mysql_select_db('***4123');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Deleted data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

So just need some help figuring out if this is syntacticly correct. what should be sent through ajax is the id-number of the row i want to be deleted in the table address

Comment: It is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use something like `intval()` or `is_int` to make sure the parameter is a number

Answer (score 3):

Your query syntax looks incorrect, especially since your escaping of the `"` is completely off.  As well as you should be using single quotes within your query for string delimiters rather than the double quotes which you are using.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM address WHERE idnum = " . $id;
```

This should work.  This is assuming that id is numeric (i.e. an integer, float, decimal, etc.).  You should always validate the provided data or at least sanitize before bringing it anywhere near the database or else someone could easily SQL inject your site.  A quick cleaning which should be available is to cast the posted value as an int.

```
$id = (int) $_POST [ 'dr' ];
```

Comment: Thank you =] I always have issues when jumping in and out of strings and such

Answer (score 1):

Use PDO.  Easier error handling and better way to sanitize data:

```
<?php
  try {
    $db = new PDO ('mysql:host=star***.***.edu;dbname=***4123', '***4123', '*****');
  }

  catch (Exception $e)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . $e->getMessage());
  }

  $statement = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM address WHERE idnum=?');

  $statement->bindParam(1, $_POST['dr']);

  if (false === $statement->execute())
  {
    die('Could not delete data: ' . print_r($pdo->errorInfo(),true));
  }
```

PDO automatically closes the connection, so there's nothing more to do.

Comment: Yes that works, but is not extremely relevant to the question which was being asked.

Comment: You're right.  My first instinct was to protect from OP's SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dr']);
$dbhost = 'star***.***.edu';
$dbuser = '***4123';
$dbpass = '*****';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = "DELETE FROM address
        WHERE idnum= '$id' ";

mysql_select_db('***4123');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Deleted data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Try to use MySQLi, Prepared Statement and never trust an input

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection - `mysql_real_escape_string` won't protect you here

Comment: edited the code to fix the remaining SQL-injection hole. You need to also escape the @var with `'` single quotes in the query string.